# Solution to $y''-\frac{2y'}x+cy=0$ by order reduction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-\frac{2y'}x+cy=0$$
I have tried many ways to reduce this form to a first-order equation but they seem to be useless. Can anyone give me a hint?

Is there any method that is better than changing to first-order?

Comment: It is not clear what is divided by what...I would assume only the 2y' by the x ?

Comment: @imranfat Yes, you are right. Sorry for my unclear writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Multiply both sides by $x$:
   $$y''(x)-\frac{2\cdot y'(x)}{x}+\text{c}\cdot y(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow x\cdot y''(x)-2\cdot y'(x)+\text{c}\cdot x\cdot y(x)=0$$
2. Apply the Laplace transformation, $\mathcal{L}_x\left[f(x)\right]_{(s)}=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\cdot y''(x)-2\cdot y'(x)+\text{c}\cdot x\cdot y(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_x\left[0\right]_{(s)}$$
3. Find the Laplace transformation term by term and factor out constants:
   $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\cdot y''(x)\right]_{(s)}-2\cdot\mathcal{L}_x\left[y'(x)\right]_{(s)}+\text{c}\cdot\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\cdot y(x)\right]_{(s)}=\mathcal{L}_x\left[0\right]_{(s)}$$
4. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\cdot y''(x)\right]_{(s)}=-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[y''(x)\right]_{(s)}\right)$$
5. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[y''(x)\right]_{(s)}=s^2\cdot\text{Y}(s)-s\cdot y(0)-y'(0)$$
6. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[y'(x)\right]_{(s)}=s\cdot\text{Y}(s)-y(0)$$
7. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[x\cdot y(x)\right]_{(s)}=-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[y(x)\right]_{(s)}\right)$$
8. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[y(x)\right]_{(s)}=\text{Y}(s)$$
9. $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[0\right]_{(s)}=0$$
10. Rewrite the equation:
    $$\text{Y}'(s)+\frac{4\cdot s\cdot\text{Y}(s)}{\text{c}+s^2}=\frac{3\cdot y(0)}{\text{c}+s^2}$$
11. Now, let
     $v(s)=\exp\left[\int\frac{4s}{\text{c}+s^2}\space\text{d}s\right]=\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2$
     Multiply both sides by $v(s)$:
    $$\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\cdot\text{Y}'(s)+\left(4\cdot s\cdot\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)\right)\cdot\text{Y}(s)=3\cdot y(0)\cdot\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)$$
12. Substitute $4\cdot s\cdot\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\left(\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\right)$:
    $$\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\cdot\text{Y}'(s)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\left(\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\right)\cdot\text{Y}(s)=3\cdot y(0)\cdot\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)$$
13. Apply the reverse product rule:
    $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\left(\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\cdot\text{Y}(s)\right)=3\cdot y(0)\cdot\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)$$
14. Integrate both sides with respect to $s$:
    $$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}\left(\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\cdot\text{Y}(s)\right)\space\text{d}s=\int3\cdot y(0)\cdot\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)\space\text{d}s$$
15. Evaluate the integrals:
    $$\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2\cdot\text{Y}(s)=3\cdot y(0)\cdot\left(\frac{s^3}{3}+\text{c}\cdot s\right)+\text{K}$$
16. Solving for $\text{Y}(s)$:
    $$\text{Y}(s)=\frac{y(0)\cdot s\cdot\left(3\cdot\text{c}+s^2\right)+\text{K}}{\left(\text{c}+s^2\right)^2}$$
17. With inverse Laplace transform, we find:
    $$y(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}}\cdot\cos\left(x\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}\right)\cdot\left(2\cdot\text{c}\cdot y(0)-\text{K}\cdot x\right)+\sin\left(x\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}}\right)\cdot\left(2\cdot\text{c}^2\cdot x\cdot y(0)+\text{K}\cdot x\right)}{2\cdot\text{c}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not focus on Laplace transform. Thank you again :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help.